# Ошибка при попытке вывести видео с камеры OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, videocapture

Пытаюсь отобразить видео с видеокамеры.

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 
while(True):
 ret, frame = cap.read()
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
 cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
   break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

При запуске возникает ошибка:

> OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Остановка происходит на строке:

`gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

при этом светодиодный индикатор на самой видеокамере загорается.
Путь указанный в ошибке: 
`D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182` 
не понимаю откуда берется. У меня вообще нет диска D: на компьютере.

`read` возвращает следующее: `ret = False`, `frame = None`

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: значит, ошибка у вас возникает на моменте чтения фрейма, а не на моменте преобразования. если framne у вас None, то дальнейший код выдаст ошибку

Comment: Сергей, вам предоставили несколько ответов и вы должны выбрать ответ, который вам больше подходит и отметить его как правильный, если вы не знаете как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import cv2


#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)                        # <----
 
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так всё заработало!!! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

нужно явно указать тип api камеры, и, желательно, делать проверку на открытие:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так работает! Большое спасибо!